# Double Integrals and Joint Probability

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

An insurance policy is written to cover a loss X where X has a density function

$$f(x) = \frac{3}{8}x^2; \qquad 0 \le x \le 2$$

The time (in hours) to process a claim of size x, where $0 \le x \le 2$, is uniformly distributed on the interval from x to 2x.

Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen claim on this policy is processed in three hours or more.

**My Work**

The problem is asking me to solve for $P[T>3]$. I'll first find the joint density function, and then integrate over the appropriate area.

$f(x,t) = f(t\mid X=x) \dot f(x) = \frac{3x^2}{8}\frac{1}{x}$ $= \frac{3x}{8}$

A graph of the area

/[image: Users/Nick/Desktop/Upload.jpg]

This leads me to $P[T>3] = \int_3^4 \int_{1.5}^2 \frac{3x}{8} \,dx\,dy = .328$

however the correct answer is 0.17. where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former parts are all right, except you didn't pay attention to the definition region of $t$.

The joint distribution of $t$ and $x$ is:
$$ f(x,t)=f_{0}(t\mid x)f(x)=3x/8~~~1\leq x\leq 2, ~x\leq t \leq 2x $$
From the graph you draw, we could see the integration should be:
$$P[T>3]=\int_3^4 dt \int_{t/2}^{2}3x/8 \, dx=0.171875$$